# How to trigger some sound on background when push notification(firebase) received ~ React Native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-sound

I am building an application similar to [Swiggy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.swiggy.android&hl=en_IN&gl=US), So When getting a new order from a customer, I am triggering a push notification, At that time I need to trigger a different Horn Sound.

Modules used:

```
// For Firebase notification
@react-native-firebase/messaging
react-native-push-notification (for local notification)


// Background lisner to trigger sound
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import SoundPlayer from 'react-native-sound-player'

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async(remoteMsg) => {
    try {
        SoundPlayer.playSoundFile('air_horn', 'mp3')
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`cannot play the sound file`, e)
    }
})
```

Here! The problem is Sound is not triggered when notification is received.

Please Help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set `sound` field into push notification payload https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support